# Cauchy's Theorem for Rectangles: Existence of a subrectangle with half the dimensions of the ambient one such that an integral condition is satisfied

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is from Palka's *An Introduction to Complex Function Theory*, page 141, for the proof of the statement:

> If a function $f$ is analytic in an open set $U$, then $\int_{\partial R}f(z)dz = 0$ for every closed rectangle $R$ in $U$.

Palka begins the proof by taking a rectangle $R$ and dividing it into four congruent rectangles $R_1^j, 1 \leq j \leq 4$. By triangle inequality Palka reasons that $|I^j_1| \geq 4^{-1}|I|$ for $I = \int_{\partial R}f(z)dz$, $I_1^j = \int_{\partial R_1^j}f(z)dz$. Then Palka states:

> It is therefore possible to assert the existence of a subrectangle $R_1$ of $R$ whose dimensions are half those of $R$ such that $I_1 = \int_{\partial R_1}f(z)dz$ satisfies $|I_1| \geq 4^{-1}|I|$.

Do we obtain such a subrectangle $R_1$ by just gluing together two neighboring rectangles $R_1^i, R_1^j, i \neq j$?

Comment: There is no need to glue anything.  Just use $$\int\limits_{\partial R_1} f(z)\,dz =\sum_{j=1}^4\,\int\limits_{\partial R^j_1} f(z)\,dz$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Ah, I see. We just rename that $R_1^i$ with $|I_1^i|$ to be $R_1$?

Comment: Yes. Besides there was a misprint in my comment. The left integral should be over $R$.